Why is there only one animation exported when I have several actions?
I have several actions tied to my rig, as you can see in the screenshot below. All of these were created by downloading Mixamo rig and then using the plugin to 'bake' it over to the main rig.

The problem that I have is when I export it, it only exports the action that is currently active. I think this is because if I look at Animation, only one is visible (and that name changes depend on which I have selected).

I have read that you want to convert these to NLA in order to export them. I have exported plenty of animations and never converted to NLA, so that doesn't seem like a must do. Now, that being said I have tried converting and what I find is that the animation no longer works. Any ideas how to fix this without converting?

If you're exporting to FBX format then under Animation in the export dialog you should uncheck "NLA Strips" and make sure the "All Actions" is ticked.

I've tried that, but it doesn't work either
